# Unable to horizontal align diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-feynman, feynman

I have these 3 Feynman diagrams. I want them in a single horizontal line but I'm unable to do so.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\section{Feynman Diagrams}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1,baseline, font=\Large,]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram [small] {
            (a1) -- [fermion,edge label={\(q\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(\ell\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(\ell-q\)}] (a2)
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \centerline{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below right=2cm and 3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram {
            (a1) -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [line width=1mm,anti fermion,edge label={\(\ell\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_3\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [anti fermion,edge label={\(q_1+q_2+\ell\)}] 
                (a4)-- [anti fermion,edge label={\(q_1+l\)}] (a2),
                (a3) -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_2\)}] (a4);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}}
            \centerline{  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, font=\footnotesize]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram {
            (a1) -- [fermion,edge label={\(p\)}] (a2) 
                -- [line width=0.8mm,fermion, half left,fermion,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a2) -- [fermion,line width=0.8mm, half right,edge label={\(q_2\)}](a5),
                (a5) --[line width=0.8mm,fermion,edge label={\(q_1+q_2-p\)}] (a2)
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (i)  you enclose two pictures in `\centerile}`. Remove this. (ii) your image is to big to be fit in one line. You my consider to increase `\textwidth`

Answer (score 2):

You need to decrease the distances to make the figure fit in one line. More importantly, I think you should not abuse the edge labels in order to indicate the momenta, rather you might want to use the momentum keys. You can also use momentum conservation to make some expressions shorter. Then it does fit in one line. The horizontal alignment is done by a matrix, which allows us in a simple way to make sure that the distances between the diagrams coincide. I also replaced `\centerline` in favor of `\centering` and put the diagrams in a figure.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\section{Feynman Diagrams}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, font=\Large]
   \matrix[column sep=1ex]{
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=1cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=1.5cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=1cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram {
            (a1) -- [fermion,momentum={\(q\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,momentum={\(\ell\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,momentum={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,momentum={\(\ell-q\)}] (a2)
            };
            \end{feynman} &
            \begin{feynman}[yshift=0.75cm]
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=1cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below=1.5cm of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[below=1.5cm of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below right=0.75cm and 1.5cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=1cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram {
            (a1) -- [fermion,momentum={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [line width=1mm,anti fermion,momentum={[thin]\(\ell\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,momentum={\(q_3\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [anti fermion,momentum={\(\ell-q_3\)}] 
                (a4)-- [anti fermion,momentum={\(q_1+\ell\)}] (a2),
                (a3) -- [fermion,momentum'={\(q_2\)}] (a4);
            };
            \end{feynman} &
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=1cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=1cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram {
            (a1) -- [fermion,momentum={\(p\)}] (a2) 
                -- [line width=0.8mm,fermion, half left,fermion,momentum={[thin]\(q_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,momentum={\(p\)}] (a6),
                (a2) -- [fermion,line width=0.8mm, half
                right,momentum'={[thin]\(q_2-q_1\)}](a5),
                (a5) --[line width=0.8mm,fermion,momentum={[thin]\(q_2\)}] (a2)
            };
            \end{feynman}\\ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that this does not require `lualatex`. In fact, sadly it does not work when compiled with `lualatex`, at least on my machine. This is already true for your code. So I *assume* you did not want to compile it with `lualatex`. This makes sense, at no point the layout algorithms are used, and that way you can upload it to the arXiv.